# Change the color of items in the more tab

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

As you can see the color of the items in the more tab stay the default blue is their a way to change them to the color of the other icons? Preferably through storyboard.

Comment: Try to change tint color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can do it only programmatically in `UITabBarController`.

This code should do the job

```
moreNavigationController.view.tintColor = .blue
```